# DevExpress Contorls change their location inside GroupControl or PanelControl when copy paste

Tags: visual-studio-2013, devexpress

I'm using devExpress 14 with VS 2013 it's so good but have some strange problems with it.  When I create a groupControl and put some controls (like textEdit and LabelControl) in it and copy it to another form, in design time I dont see any problem but when I run the form, the controls inside the groupControl change their location.  I searched a lot but no one mentioned that.  [image: Here is an image of what happens.]

Comment: Provide mode details or snap shot for such type of problem and try to provide designer code for these buttons or textedit.. There may be some anchoring issue during form resize..

Comment: Oh I forgot to say that, for simplicity I made the form fixed dialog.  Change location happens When the form loads.

Comment: why do you not use layout controls to keep their position consistent with screen resolution..

Comment: I really like your idea and I do this always when I use Standard .Net Controls But this make things even more complex and unstable in the case of DevExpress. the same error will happen on all the controls.

Comment: well give it a try.. Hope this will solve your problem or you can use DevExpress layout controls..